# Haskell type issue regarding conversion to a float

Tags: haskell

I have the following code to test for primeness

```
prime x n = if (n==1) then True else (if (mod x n == 0) then False else prime x (n-1))
```

However I want to create a separate function so that I have to input only 1 number, like so:

```
isPrime x = prime x (floor(sqrt(x)))
```

However, I am getting an error when I try this:

```
 Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `isPrime'
  prevents the constraint `(Integral a0)' from being solved.
```

I also wanted to try using partial functions to apply this but I couldn't get that to work either. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to avoid floating point operations as much as possible. Floating point operations are "approximative", so that means small rounding errors can generate a lot of trouble. Usually "integer land" is more safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler to solve by not computing a square root in the first place. Instead, start with small values of `n` and work *up* to the square root of `x` (which you can detect by comparing `n * n` and `x`).

```
-- Treat 1 and 2 as base cases so we can increment n a little faster;
-- The interesting values of n are the odd integers 3, 5, 7, ...
prime 1 _ = False
prime 2 _ = True
prime x n | n * n > x = True
          | mod x n == 0 = False
          | otherwise = prime x (n + 2)

isPrime x = prime x 3
```

(It's less efficient, as computing `n*n` repeatedly is more expensive than computing a square root. But if you are concerned about efficiency, then you'll implement the Sieve of Erastosthenes or something similar, rather than testing every potential odd factor.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, more important than solving the problem to me is more knowing where I went wrong, as I'm doing the problem set at the moment mainly to learn haskell, as opposed to using haskell to solve an important problem. If it's possible, I would love a brief explanation as to why Haskell doesn't like the code I did, in a general kind of way?

Comment: `sqrt` is polymorphic in its return value, and `floor` is polymorphic in its argument. Though it doesn't really matter which type you choose for `sqrt` to return and `floor` to accept (`Float` and `Double` would both work), the typechecker refuses to pick one arbitrarily. You have to be explicit.